# How should I replace these pressure reducing valves?

Tags: plumbing, boiler, water-pressure

At my church, we have a fairly old boiler system. The system was just passed for annual inspection, but it is failing to refill after having been drained. There is absolutely no water flowing past the reducing valves (yes, plural), and the one with a fast-fill handle on it is rusted solid.

So the way these are connected is:

```
Water Main
|
|
Shut-off valve
|
|
One-way Check Valve
|
|
Pressure reducing valve #1
|
Pressure reducing valve #2 -----------------------
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
"Backflow preventer" (Per the church janitor)     |
                                            |-----Expansion Tank
```

Reducing valve #1 is a simple 1/2" valve with a jam nut on top. Reducing valve #2 is similar, but has a fast-fill handle on top as well and instead of just being a pass-through style, there's a third fitting on the bottom that goes over to a big brass valve on the expansion tank.

My questions are thus:

1. Is there really a need for 2 valves?
2. When purchasing a replacement, do I need to match anything specific?
3. Once the new valve(s) is(are) installed, how would I go about adjusting them?

Comment: So I just did a little bit of research and found that it's not 2 reducing valves, but a reducing valve/pressure relief valve combo unit. The handle that I thought was a fast-fill handle is actually on the relief valve, and the fact that it's rusted closed frightens me.

Comment: While ASCII art is neat, actual pictures would be more helpful.